# Styling Raw elements Generated from JSP tagds with Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, jquery-mobile

I have a JSP page which I need to style with JQM. The catch is all the html elements are generated by a JSP tag library (EMC Documentum wdk  framework ). The problem is I cannot add JQM attributes to these JSP tags to style them as they throw an exception stating that JQM attributes are invalid attributes (this is how normally JSP tags work).
JQM automatically applies default styling to these generated html elements. But what I want is to change some of these JQM styling and add what I want. For example there are three buttons generated on my page. After JQM applies its default styling to these buttons they appear as block level elements and they occupy the entire width of the page. I want to change them to be inline buttons so that they appear in one row and their width becomes the width of their content. Much appreciate if someone could guide me to do this in the best way possible as I have to be very concerned about the speed of the page loading. 
I would like to know
1) How to add a class
2) How to change an attribute (ex: data-theme)
3) The best possible page event to achieve 1) and 2)

The following is what I'm trying to do

```
   <dmf:html>
    <dmf:head>
        <dmf:webform />
            <script src='<%=Form.makeUrl(request, "/global/pages/pwcspecific/web/mobile/js/jqueryMobile/jquery-1.9.1.js")%>'></script>
            <script src='<%=Form.makeUrl(request, "/global/pages/pwcspecific/web/mobile/js/jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js")%>'></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=Form.makeUrl(request,"/global/pages/pwcspecific/web/mobile/js/jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css")%>">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <script>
                $(document).on('pageinit', '#dmsMobile', function () {
                    // This is where I try to change the things..
                        $('#btn1').addClass("ui-btn-inline");
                        $('#btn2').addClass("ui-btn-inline");
                        $('#btn3').addClass("ui-btn-inline");
                });
            </script>
    </dmf:head>
    <dmf:body >
        <dmf:form>
            <div data-role="page" id="dmsMobile">
                <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                    -------
                </div>

                <div data-role="content">
                    <!--buttons generated by JSP tags. These styled by JQM with default stying 
                    (block level and occupies the entire width of the page)
                    -->
                    <button type="button" id="btn1">Button1</button>
                    <button type="button" id="btn2">Button2</button>
                    <button type="button" id="btn3">Button3</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </dmf:form> 
    </dmf:body>
</dmf:html>
```

Regards!

Comment: Add `data-inline="true"` to anchors.

Comment: Hi Omar, Could you explain this a little bit.I'm very new to jquery. Did you mean $('#btn1').attr("data-inline", "true") ?

Comment: Yes, but if you want to set dynamically `$("#btn").buttonMarkup({ "inset": true});` or add the attribute statically to anchor tag.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned in the description that it is not possible to add any JQM attributes to tags as JSP tags do not accept anything other than its won attributes. This is how JSP tags work. JSP tags are validated before they are rendered. If I can add data-inline="true" to the JSP tag then I don't have a query to post here..

Comment: $("#btn").buttonMarkup({ "data-inline": true}); doesn't work

Comment: I just noticed you're using `button` not `a`. with `button` you dont need `type=button`, it works for `input`.

Comment: `.buttonMarkup` does work http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/W9LhJ/